# singly linked list in c# using extension method

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list, extension-methods

1. why extension method does not return the modified node in Insertion operations.
2. But It Working Fine at the time of Linked list Creation.
3. Extension method should return the modified Node.
4. What is the perfect way to do this.
5. IS extension method good in performance

Code follows

```
public class Node
{
    public Object Data { get; set; }
    public Node NextNode { get; set; }
}
public static class ListOperations
{
    public static void CreateLinkedList(this Node node, Object data)
    {
        if (node.Data == null)
        {
            node.Data = data;
        }
        else
        {
            Node newnode = new Node();
            newnode.Data = data;
            Node current = new Node();
            current = node;
            while (current.NextNode != null)
            {
                current = current.NextNode;
            }
            current.NextNode = newnode;
            node = current;
        }
    }
    public static void InsertNode(this Node node1, Object data, int position)
    {

        Node newnode = new Node();
        newnode.Data = data;
        if (position == 1)
        {
            newnode.NextNode = node1;
            node1 = newnode;

        }

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        //random Singly LinkedList
        node.CreateLinkedList(10);
        node.CreateLinkedList(11);
        node.CreateLinkedList(12);
        node.CreateLinkedList(13);
        node.CreateLinkedList(14);
        node.CreateLinkedList(15);
        node.InsertNode(20, 1);// this method does not return node value what is inserted.


    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot reassign `this` in an extension method ([yet](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/186)).

Comment: `InsertNode` is void that's why it doesn't return anything

Comment: what shoud i do??

Comment: Instead of void, you can just return "Node", and in the function, return "current".

Comment: Change void to Node as return type of `InsertNode` method and return `newnode` from the method. Also read more about returning values from method and extension method.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: i tried but it gave me same result..

Comment: Debugging does not change the result but it helps you find the issue in your code.

Comment: Why do you want to create extension methods for this? These are your operations on the `Node` Data type. Keep them as methods of your type. Also the definition of your methods is not appropriate. Your createlist actually creates only one node.

Comment: @sidprasher I'll with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your code, and we can deal with them later. But let's answer your questions first. I will be a bit literal and direct, since I can't assume why you have done it the way it is done.

> why extension method does not return the modified node in Insertion operations.

Since your method doesn't return anything

> But It Working Fine at the time of Linked list Creation.

Yes, since that code doesn't ever modify the `this Node node` parameter

> Extension method should return the modified Node.

Only if you actually return any data from the method!

> What is the perfect way to do this.

See below

> IS extension method good in performance

Extension method compared with what? Compared with member method written similarly, there should really be no performance difference in the cases relevant to your example

**Perfect way to do it:**

So first things first: There is no need to write an extension method here. Why wouldn't you write a regular member method? Extensions are usually done when the class you want to add the functionality is not directly available for you to edit, typically as the code belongs to a third party

Second, you don't quite seem to understand the references and how the pass-by-value works. First let me post a better code, and then explain it

```
public class Node {
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public Node NextNode { get; set; }

    public Node(object data) {
        Data = data;
    }

    public Node AppendNode(object data) {
        var newNode = new Node(data);

        var current = this;
        while (current.NextNode != null)
            current = current.NextNode;
        current.NextNode = newNode;

        return newNode;
    }

    public Node SetFirstNode(object data) {
        return new Node(data) { NextNode = this };
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var linkedList = new Node(10);
        linkedList.AppendNode(11);
        linkedList.AppendNode(12);
        linkedList.AppendNode(13);
        linkedList.AppendNode(14);
        linkedList.AppendNode(15);
        linkedList = linkedList.SetFirstNode(20);

    }
}
```

The important things to notice from the perspective of your main question (why the insert did not work) is that the method `SetFirstNode` actually returns the newly created node and in `Main`, we re-assign the linkedlist as such `linkedList = linkedList.SetFirstNode(20);`

Now, you can actually write a static method and pass by ref the linkedlist, but that is not a good practice, in my opinion. Nevertheless, the code would look like below

```
public static class ListOperations {
    public static void InsertNode(ref Node linkedList, object data) {
        linkedList = new Node(data) { NextNode = linkedList };
    }
}
```

Among other things to notice, I am calling the `node` object as `linkedList`, `CreateLinkedList` as `AppendNode` and `InsertNode` as `SetFirstNode` on purpose, so you can understand the code better.

Below is the same code with generic argument instead of `object Data` and using a proper `InsertNode` method

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Data.ToString();
    }

    public Node(T data) {
        Data = data;
    }

    public Node<T> AppendNode(T data) {
        var newNode = new Node<T>(data);

        var current = this;
        while (current.Next != null)
            current = current.Next;
        current.Next = newNode;

        return newNode;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a new node into the linkedlist as the desired position
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">0-based index for the final position of new node</param>
    /// <param name="newNode">The newly created node containing data</param>
    /// <returns>returns the first node of the linkedlist</returns>
    public Node<T> InsertNode(T data, int position, out Node<T> newNode) {
        var current = this;
        position--;
        newNode = new Node<T>(data);
        if (position < 0) {
            newNode.Next = current;
            return newNode;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < position; ++i)
            current = current.Next;
        newNode.Next = current.Next;
        current.Next = newNode;
        return this;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var linkedList = new Node<int>(10);
        linkedList.AppendNode(11);
        linkedList.AppendNode(12);
        linkedList.AppendNode(13);
        linkedList.AppendNode(14);
        linkedList.AppendNode(15);
        linkedList = linkedList.InsertNode(20, 0, out var newNode);
    }
}
```